# HTML5 Database - increase size above 5mb without prompting to user

Tags: html, local-storage

Is there anyway to change the html5 DB storage space from 5mb without asking the user ? (I'm interested most for Firefox browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no.

You could however use *IndexedDB*...

**IndexedDB:**

Browsers will ask the user for permission if the DB tries to use more than their specified limit (50MB in Firefox's case I think). Once permission is obtained there is no further permission requests though.

**LocalStorage:**

The limit is 5MB for all browsers. This cannot be changed.

Comment: The limit actually can be changed, at least from Firefox in about:config key dom.storage.default_quota. However, the user must do this, it cannot be done from a web page.